Is there a scheme-theoretic definition for the center of an algebraic group (or group scheme)?
Since this is the case for other usual group-theoretic concepts like normal subgroups or derived subgroup (i.e. commutator), I was wondering if there exists a similar construction for an object equivalent to the center of a group in the context of algebraic groups (or group schemes).

this might be relevant
